# MySQL COMMENT

Tags: mysql

Хотелось бы знать, есть ли уже готовые реализации просмотра комментариев для столбцов кроме как "SHOW CREATE tablename". В гугле гуглил - мало что нашел, натыкаюсь в основном на то, как писать обычные комменты аля "//".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    column_comment,column_name
FROM 
    information_schema.columns
WHERE 
    table_name = 'table'
```

здесь `table` - название таблицы. если добавить условие `column_name = 'имя_столбца'` то получим описания нужного столбца.